# Performance of unpack()

Tags: php, performance, zephir

I wrote a PHP class in Zephir to increase performance, but it is still very slow and memory consuming. To compare, I wrote several variants of the same code, but `unpack()` is always nearly as slow at storing the data in a csv file.

Is there any way to optimize this code? About 30% of the whole program time is spent in unpack.

```
class Hdb implements \Iterator, \Countable {
    /**
     * File handle.
     * @var resource
     */
    protected fh;

    protected line_count = 0;
    protected position = 0;

    protected row = [];

    public function __construct(string file) -> void {
        let this->line_count = floor((filesize(file)) / 12);
        let this->fh = fopen(file, "r");
    }

    public function readLine() {
        var timestamp;
        var value;
        var status;

        let timestamp = unpack("L", fread(this->fh, 4));
        let value     = unpack("f", fread(this->fh, 4));
        let status    = unpack("I", fread(this->fh, 4));

        let this->position++;

        return [
            "timestamp": timestamp[1],
            "value":     value[1],
            "status":    status[1]
        ];
    }

    // ... The standard Iterator stuff.
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/GreenRover/2480f7373929c71864fc)

Comment: Please include the rest of the code ("The standard Iterator stuff."), otherwise your question may be closed due to incomplete code.

Comment: The desire to improve code is implied for all questions on this site. Question titles should reflect the purpose of the code, not how you wish to have it reworked. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your performance issue is caused by going to file multiple times. The more you read in at once the less time you'll spend asking the operating system to provide you with a few more bytes for unpack to operate on.

Similar to the above answer:

```
$data = fread(fh,12);
$a = unpack("L",substr($data,0,4));
$b = unpack("f",substr($data,4,4));
$c = unpack('I',substr($data,8,4));
```

If you want to reorganize your code you could load the entire file and then work on the data within it.

```
$packed = file_get_contents("somefile.dat");
$len  = strlen($packed);

$offset = 0;
while ( $offset < $len )
{
  $a[] = unpack("L",$packed,$offset,4);
  $b[] = unpack("f",$packed,$offset+4,4);
  $c[] = unpack("I",$packed,$offset+8,4);
  $offset += 12;
}
```

Of course, you may have to reorganize various sections of code to support working on larger chunks of the input data at a time.

Note: It appears that unpacked is being unfairly blamed for being slow due to the filesystem access embedded in the function call. You might also want to do a few tests to clarify what is taking time in the small chunk method and see how much it speeds up based on increasing the read size used (if you have the time and inclination).

EDIT: Adding the following after comments.

You are right. I did some tests and while reading more data at once does save time it isn't as significant as reducing calls to unpack.

```
Running unpack on binary file (12 byte reads, 3 unpacks per read)...
... fread time: 3.5979931354523
... unpack time: 12.179003238678
... total measured time: 15.77699637413
... records: 265533

Running unpack on binary file (preload file, 3 unpacks per 12 bytes)...
... fread time: 0.016999959945679
... unpack time: 12.446995973587
... total measured time: 12.463995933533
... records: 265533

Running unpack on binary file (preload file, 12 bytes per unpack)...
... fread time: 0.01200008392334
... unpack time: 4.1770012378693
... total measured time: 4.1890013217926
... records: 265533

Running unpack on binary file (preload, 24 bytes per unpack)...
... fread time: 0.010999917984009
... unpack time: 2.189001083374
... total measured time: 2.200001001358
... records: 265534 (* padding added at end of input)
```

Run using PHP with microtime(true) capture before and after relevant actions.

EDIT: With a bit more fooling around I can now give you an "answer" regarding how to increase performance.

Split your data internally in order to get as much work as possible out of a single call to unpack.

```
if ( 1 )
{
  echo "<br>\n";
  echo "Running unpack on binary file (preload, split into 3 streams, unpack each stream)...<br>\n";
  ob_flush();
  flush();

  $records = 0;
  $fread_time = 0.0;
  $unpack_time = 0.0;
  $measured = 0.0;

  $start = microtime(true);
  $data  = file_get_contents($bin_file);
  $size  = filesize($bin_file);
  $stop  = microtime(true);
  $fread_time = $stop - $start;

  $Ldata = '';
  $fdata = '';
  $Idata = '';
  $offset = 0;
  $start = microtime(true);
  while ($offset < $size) 
  {
    $Ldata .= substr($data,$offset,4);
    $offset += 4;
    $fdata .= substr($data,$offset,4);
    $offset += 4;
    $Idata .= substr($data,$offset,4);
    $offset += 4;

    $records++;
  }
  $stop = microtime(true);
  $split_time = $stop - $start;

  $start = microtime(true);
  $a = unpack('L*',$Ldata);
  $b = unpack('f*',$fdata);
  $c = unpack('I*',$Idata);
  $stop = microtime(true);
  $unpack_time += ($stop - $start);
  $measured_time = $fread_time + $split_time + $unpack_time;

  echo "... fread time: $fread_time<br>\n";
  echo "... split_time: $split_time<br>\n";
  echo "... unpack time: $unpack_time<br>\n";
  echo "... total measured time: $measured_time<br>\n";
  echo "... records: $records<br>\n";
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}
```

This provides a much better time.

```
Running unpack on binary file (preload, split into 3 streams, unpack each stream)...
... fread time: 0.013000011444092
... split_time: 0.29400014877319
... unpack time: 0.54299998283386
... total measured time: 0.85000014305115
... records: 265533
```

Hopefully this is a bit more useful.

Comment: Sorry but fread is not the problem, unpack is it.   Here what i measured: 

* Load bin 3 fread & 3 unpacks 2.4139s rows: 265533
* Load bin 1 fread & 3 unpacks 2.6356s rows: 265533
* Load bin 1 fread & 1 unpacks 1.5882s rows: 265533

Comment: Here the full demo code: https://gist.github.com/GreenRover/2480f7373929c71864fc/d26e1350fd2abe4b25ff6997a9ff1aa6b0b51475

Comment: Thanks for the additional details. I'd say they are both problems but the unpack is certainly the larger problem. I'm not sure how many unpacks you can combine but I did notice poor performance when throwing a single huge format string at unpack. ;)

Comment: I've added a split of the source file into three streams to optimize use of unpack... but I suspect you may have to be wary of running on machines with varied data type sizes... based on 32bit or 64bit architectures/PHP builds.

Comment: Ok your newst version looks great if you read the full file. But isnt the best solution fi you just need to read a time range. But combine both and read blocks of 10 lines, can be godd idea.

Answer (score 0):

This code can be improved by combining the unpack.

```
let timestamp = unpack("L", fread(this->fh, 4));
let value     = unpack("f", fread(this->fh, 4));
let status    = unpack("I", fread(this->fh, 4));
```

To

```
let d = unpack("L1timestamp/f1value/L1status", fread(handle, 12));
d["timestamp"];
d["value"];
d["status"];
```

Comment: For the sake of having a complete and well written answer, could you please add *why this improves the performance*?

Comment: I am not shure why it is faster, i just tested it and use a combined unpack is mutch faster then 3 simple unpacks.